# cannot run jenkins, even after clearing it's directory

Tags: java, jenkins

Tried to upgrade jenkins today. It doesn't start anymore.

Even if i try to remove its directory, it recreates it cleanly but then crashes with following log.

```
[#|2013-04-24T07:24:49.849+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=106;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|jenkins was successfully deployed in 3,800 milliseconds.|#]

[#|2013-04-24T07:24:50.100+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|jenkins.InitReactorRunner|_ThreadID=152;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Listed all plugins|#]

[#|2013-04-24T07:24:50.100+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|jenkins.InitReactorRunner|_ThreadID=152;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Failed Loading plugins
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1.run(PluginManager.java:324)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:888)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2013-04-24T07:24:50.102+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.WebAppMain|_ThreadID=143;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Failed to initialize Jenkins
org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:246)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:43)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:899)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:801)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:214)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1.run(PluginManager.java:324)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:888)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

Jenkins 1.512 on Glassfish 3.1.2.2

EDIT: version 1.421 works. Version 1.422 fails. This is consistent, even after wiping jenkins directory.

Comment: try to run the new version without upgrade as in fresh installation and see if it works.

Comment: that's what I think I did: undeploy / remove jenkins directory / restart app server / deploy. Then I got this, again.

Comment: are you sure that you do not have previous Jenkins config some where. I guess its Jenkins_home or something. If you are sure that means the new version has issues. Are you running it in glassfish?

Comment: I guess something is still there, but I can't see what. What do you mean by "Jenkins_home"? Some environment variable? Jenkins config was in /home/glassfish/.hudson. I removed that and it created a new /home/glassfish/.jenkins, as expected.

Comment: FYI, opened https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17743

Comment: looks like some issue with glassfish may be as the same version works for me in tomcat. JENKINS_HOME env variable makes Jenkins store configuration in the set folder.

Comment: This has worked for years on the same server, which has been on GF 2.1 to 3.1.2.2. It works with Jenkins 1.512.

Comment: 1.512 works standalone (although I get a 500 Server error and another stack trace if I try to open any view).

Comment: You should check that Jenkins 1.512 version is compatible with ALL your plugins that you have installed, not only with glassfish.

Comment: It seems it is: it runs in standalone. Plus, I didn't install anything outside quite basic plugins (git, ...). And if I remove my jenkins directory, I guess all my plugins are gone, but jenkins (war) won't start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this, and I had 2 virtual servers:

https://gist.github.com/andrewg4153/3693577

> If you have a Glassfish domain with multiple virtual servers, you will
>   be tempted to select them all when you deploy the Jenkins CI web
>   application. This is a bad thing to do, as the Jenkins core code
>   contains a singleton class:
>   http://sorcerer.jenkins-ci.org/source-view.html?jenkins/model/Jenkins.js#678
>   When you do this, you'll get the following in your logs:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: second instance at
>   jenkins.model.Jenkins.(Jenkins.java:744) at
>   hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:81) at
>   hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:77) at
>   hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:217) Just deploy to one of the
>   virtual servers, and everything will be okay.

I deployed on 1 of them and it now works!

Well, I guess it's the bug to fix...

Comment: just for reference, using the cli the command would be: `asadmin deploy --virtualservers <vserver-name> jenkins.war`

Answer (score 1):

According to the stack trace you provided: Perhaps there is some missing plug-in [Task Scanner Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Task+Scanner+Plugin) or its dependency that is breaking your Jenkins instance?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1.run(PluginManager.java:324)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
```

Comment: Removing jenkins directory or plugins subdir doesn't help (no effect). Should I try to manually install some plugin?

Comment: @ymajoros Is the stacktrace the same when you try to run a clean (without any additional plug-ins) Jenkins installation? Have you tried to uninstall unnecessary plug-ins from within Jenkins UI (in the old versin which works?) I would rather try to stick to normal way of installing/uninstalling Jenkins plugins - and would not advise to delete any Jenkins dir.

Comment: Same stacktrace on clean install :-( I'd like to use jenkis normally, too. I deleted its dir to try to have a clean install. The only additional plugins I have are for git (when not running from clean install). Standalone mode works.

Comment: @ymajoros I thought that you could try to use something other then Glassfish for Jenkins deployment? Like e.g. Tomcat? If Jenkins would work fine, then you would nail down the problem to Glassfish - if not, then it's a Jenkins issue (not dependent on Glassfish).

Comment: it runs standalone ("java -jar jenkins.war", which launches Winstone). It's probably a Jenkins issue that affects Glassfish on my system. No idea how to go further, Glassfish works perfectly for all my applications on same install. Do you have some idea?

Comment: @ymajoros from what you are writing its rather Glassfish affecting Jenkins. I would wait for the open issue on Jenkins - perhaps it turns out to be a known issue. I would also try a clean Glassfish installation perhaps on another computer and clean Jenkins install. To check if this issue still exist - if it is still present - then at least you would have best environment for testing this bug/issue.  It will show the smallest subset of "interesed parties". Hope this helps and you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins version 1.422 had a booting issue. 1.423 was supposed to fix it.  My suggestion would be to clean install 1.423 and see if that solves the issue.  If it does, try upgrading from there.

Comment: Tried that, just the same. The strange thing is, I've been upgrading quite regularly last year, so I know I must have had 1.450+ versions running for a long time. And I upgrading beginning of April to the then latest version. It did work, but I had some problems, probably with git plugin (that was the reason why I upgraded to 1.512). Now, no version I tried above 1.421 works in glassfish.