# Jenkins Crashes after installing GitHub Plugin

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have a question about updating GitHub plugin.

Everytime I do an update plugin such as GitHub and restart the jenkins, Jenkins start crashing. when I try to access jenkins through URL in my browser, the error page shows up with some exception "class not found jenkins/model jenkins" . and then in order to make jenkins working again , I have to delete the plugin entirely from the plugins directory. I wish someone has an answer for this because I really need to make my github projects available to jenkins for build. Thanks

Comment: As a workaround you could always use a deployment key on your Github repository, then use the Git plugin and setup the service hook in Github using the Git plugin instead.

Comment: Now I am in a bigger problem, i tried to install just the Git plugin and as always jenkins crashed... so i removed the plugin from the directory and restarted the jenkins, but now its constantly crashing even after I removed that plugin.

Comment: Have you checked the Jenkins logs to see if it's logging anything before it crashes, or why it can't start successfully?

Comment: Well my hudson is installed in /var/lib/hudson. I do see a folder 'log' in there but it hasnt been modified since last year. there is nothing related with log in my hudson installation directory. however when I access the jenkins through browser, I get the following stack trace:    org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/model/Jenkins
 at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:246)
 at hudson.model.Hudson.executeReactor(Hudson.java:753)
 at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:667)
 at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:607)

Comment: If I plug `org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException` into Google, it seems like it's a plugin update gone wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007811/jenkins-critical-error-after-plugin-update and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184035/cannot-run-jenkins-even-after-clearing-its-directory are somewhat recent Stack Overflow questions on the topic

Comment: I guess this exception is more generic. I cant find anything about java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/model/Jenkins   anywhere. Seems like I am the only one having this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very usual problem with Jenkins. My workaround was to either update the jenkins (where ever it is installed) and restarting the hudson service. 
sometimes even restarting the service works. 
often you might need to remove those plugins from within (/var/lib/hudson/plugins/) and restart the service.